# Reading Optional Standard Input Without Blocking

Tags: shell, unix, cat

So I have a function which can optionally be provided with extra data via standard input, which I'm grabbing with `cat`, however, when there is no standard input `cat` will block execution.

Here's a silly example:

```
foo() { echo "$@" "$(cat)"; }
```

Basically it echoes everything given as input via both arguments and standard input.

Is there a way to prevent `cat` from blocking in this case? Currently I'm having to work around this by only calling `cat` if an option to do-so is set, but it seems like really all I should need is for `cat` to return nothing if there's nothing to read.

Comment: It doesn't/can't know there is nothing to read versus there is nothing *yet* (slow link, human hasn't started typing yet, etc.) You could try to use `read` with a timeout to get the first character/line and then only use `cat` if that succeeds but that is going to race on slow input.

Comment: Okay, but I'm only interested in content being piped into `foo`, rather than arbitrary standard input (should have said), i.e- simply calling `foo` would be incorrect, it should either be called as `foo "bar"` or `echo "bar" | foo`, is there some way to distinguish that, e.g- can I check whether standard input is global (same as the one my script got)?

Comment: You can test for standard input being a terminal with the `test`/`[` `-t` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo() {
  if [ -t 0 ]
  then
    echo "$@"
  else
    echo "$@" "$(cat)"
  fi
}
```